# On a contour integral with conjugate

Tags: complex-analysis

im struggling with the following exercise.
I had to show that for all R>1, f holomorphic on the open disk of center O and of radius R.

$  \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(e^{i\theta}) cos^2(\frac{\theta}{2})d\theta= 2f(0)+f'(0)   $ and $  \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(e^{i\theta}) sin^2(\frac{\theta}{2})d\theta= 2f(0)-f'(0)$

Which i managed to do without trouble.
But now i have to evaluate the following integral for $|a| \neq 1$,

$ I(a)= \frac {1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{\overline{f(z)}}{z-a}      $

I tried adding the two first equalities that i got but it doesn't seems to give anything interesting. Since $\overline{f(z)}$ is not holomorphic in general i do not know what direction to go next, so maybe you could give me an hint !

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is $I(a)$?

Comment: What is the contour $\gamma$?

Comment: $I(a)$ is only the integral defined as i wrote it.
The contour $\gamma$ is not specified so probably a circle with a radius bigger than $R$ centered on $O.$
The only thing that is didn't wrote which was in the exercise is that they told us to use $ \int_{|z|<1} [2\pm(z+\frac{1}{z})] \frac {f(z)}{z} dz $

Comment: If $I(a)$ is *defined* as that integral then what do you want to show?

Comment: We have to evaluate the value of this integral for every $ a\in \mathbb{C}, |a| \neq 1$
I’m sorry it’s because of my English, the integral is defined as what I wrote initially and I want to evaluate the value It takes.

Comment: It may be helpful to note that $z\mapsto \overline{f(z)}$ is not holomorphic, but $z\mapsto \overline{f(\overline{z})}$ is. If $\gamma$ is the unit circle you could change variables $z\mapsto \overline z$...

Comment: I think your hint gave me the solution. Is this correct :
If $ \gamma$ is the unit circle and use the change of variables $z↦ \overline{z}$ we get  $I(a)=\frac {1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{\overline{f(z)}}{z-a}dz$ = $\int_{\overline{\gamma}} \frac{ \overline f((\overline{z})) }{ (\overline{z})-a} d \overline{z} $.  Since we can show that $ g(z)=\overline f((\overline{z})) $is holomorphic on the disk centered on $ 0$ and of radius $r<R$. We can use Cauchy's Theorem to get $ I(a)= 2\pi i f(a)$

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming $\gamma$ is the unit circle oriented counterclockwise, and $f(z)$ is holomorphic within $|z|<1$.
Setting $g(z) := \overline{f(\overline z)}$, which is holomorphic in $z$, we have
\begin{align}
I(a) &= \frac 1{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{\overline{f}(z)}{z-a}d z
\\
&=\frac 1{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\overline{f}(e^{i\phi})}{e^{i\phi}-a}e^{i\phi}d \phi
\\
&=\frac 1{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\overline{f}(e^{-i\phi})}{e^{-i\phi}-a}e^{-i\phi}d \phi
\\
&=\frac 1{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{g(e^{i\phi})}{1-a e^{i\phi}}d \phi
\\
&=\frac 1{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{g(z)}{1-az}\frac {d z}z
\\
&=Res(\frac{g(z)}{(1-az)z},z=0)
\\
&=g(0)
\\
&=f(0),
\end{align}
assuming $|a|<1$, otherwise if $|a|>1$ we also get $Res(\frac{g(z)}{(1-az)z},z=1/a)=-g(1/a)$.

Comment: I am supposed to not have seen the residue theorem but since I know i think this is a good answer ! It looks like it is the correct way to do what I tried to do in the comments above thanks!